# How to navigate with a custom button without changing styling?

Tags: swift, swiftui

If I don't use `.disabled(true)` then the button does not navigate.  If I used `.disabled(true)` then the style changes to make the foreground a grayed version of the foreground color.  I want to navigate without changing the style of my custom button. I used a non-custom button in the example to save space.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: ContentView2(),
                label: {
                    Button(action: {}, label: {
                        Text("Button")
                    }).disabled(true)
                })
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct ContentView2: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("wdfokjokjokjokjwdofjk")
            .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of making your own `Button`, just use `Text`. When you are doing `.disabled(true)` to make a button active, something is definitely wrong...

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: ContentView2()) {
                Text("Button")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a custom button I want to use.

Comment: @ScottyBlades just style the Text instead of styling the button. NavigationLink should take in something that isn't tappable, not a button (because pressing the button fires the button's own action, but doesn't fire the navigation link)

Comment:  I was hoping SwiftUI wouldn't force me to do that...I'll try that.

Comment: I find its difficult to encapsulate when I've modified both the button itself and the view it holds.  Do you tend to only modify the view it holds?

Comment: @ScottyBlades by "the view it holds" you mean the Text/label inside the button? Yeah I usually just modify that

Comment: Yes that is what I meant.

Comment: If you only modify the View inside the button, then the button animation applies to the whole button which is super awkward.

Comment: @ScottyBlades maybe `.animation(nil)`?

Comment: Seems promising.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `isActive` parameter for the `NavigationLink` and set it as an invisible background or overlay:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var navLinkActive = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Button(action: {
                navLinkActive = true
            }, label: {
                Text("Button")
            })
            .buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle())
            .background(NavigationLink(
                        destination: ContentView2(),
                        isActive: $navLinkActive,
                        label: {
                           EmptyView()
                        }))
        }
    }
}

struct CustomButtonStyle : ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .background(configuration.isPressed ? Color.red : Color.green)
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to do that either.  I'll play with that too. Ty.